# Delphi check if port is not blocked by firewall

Tags: delphi, windows-firewall, windows-firewall-api

I'm trying to write a function that can determine if a port is blocked by firewall rules, so far I found something but it doesn't seems to work... the `bAllowed` and `bRestricted` variables remain always set to false.

```
function IsTCPPortAllowed(p_nPort: Integer; p_sAddress: string): Boolean;
var
  bAllowed, bRestricted: Boolean;
  oFwMgr               : OLEVariant;
  oResult              : HRESULT;
begin
  bAllowed    := False;
  bRestricted := False;
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    try
      oFwMgr  := CreateOLEObject('HNetCfg.FwMgr');
      oResult := oFwMgr.IsPortAllowed('', NET_FW_IP_VERSION_V4, p_nPort, p_sAddress, NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP, bAllowed, bRestricted);
    except
    end;
  finally
    oFwMgr       := VarNull;
    CoUninitialize;
  end;

  if oResult = S_OK then
    Result := bAllowed and not bRestricted;
end;
```

Am I missing something here, or maybe there is another(better) way to find if a port is blocked by firewall?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's going to be next to impossible. Who says that the Windows firewall is the only firewall. There are other software firewalls. And what about the possibility of router firewalls? Why do you even need to know?

Comment: Use `WordBool` for those parameters. But anyway, that may happen if you don't have allowed or restricted port you specify for all applications for TCP protocol.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Some clients that uses our services cannot connect to them, so I have to write a tool that can say either the port is used by another application or is blocked by firewall(from what I know, they do not have another software firewall beside windows firewall)

Comment: It really sounds like this is the wrong solution to the problem. This is a system admin problem. For which tools exist a plenty. Making more tools, especially if you are not an expert in the field, is likely to make matters worse.

Comment: Since Windows Firewall finally works all-right, we can safely assume what the other **personal** firewalls are obsolete and should be ignored.

Comment: If you're dealing with firewall issues, I'm guessing you're using a known port (eg. some ISPs block outgoing SMTP or incoming HTTP), or you're trying to listen and accept incoming connections. For the later, many systems have been engineered to fall back to a central hub that can accept incoming connections in case the client can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work, I had to use `OleVariant` type for `bAllowed` and `bRestricted` variables, also I removed the `try ... except` block and checked the return status of `IsPortAllowed` as @mjn sugested.

Here is the updated version which works:

```
function IsTCPPortAllowed(p_nPort: Integer; p_sAddress: string): Boolean;
var
  bAllowed, bRestricted: OleVariant;
  oFwMgr               : OleVariant;
  oResult              : HRESULT;
begin
  bAllowed    := False;
  bRestricted := False;
  Result      := False;

  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    oFwMgr  := CreateOLEObject('HNetCfg.FwMgr');
    oResult := oFwMgr.IsPortAllowed('', NET_FW_IP_VERSION_V4, p_nPort, p_sAddress, NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP, bAllowed, bRestricted);
    if oResult = S_OK then
      Result := bAllowed and not bRestricted;
  finally
    oFwMgr    := VarNull;
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

- You are not checking the result of the [IsPortAllowed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method API call at all.  Check if it is one of the documented error codes.
- and I guess that `p_sAddress: string` has to be casted to a PChar in the API call.
- the code has an empty `except` block, this should be either removed, or the exception should at least be logged - maybe there is an exception thrown here which is swallowed

---

The IsPortAllowed method [API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) also says that

> [... For Windows Vista and later, use
>   of the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security API is recommended.]

Comment: Hi, I added the check, it returns S_OK but still the same values for `bAllowed` and `bRestricted`